# Extended WPF Toolkit: Not showing up after installing trough NuGet

Tags: wpf, xceed, wpf-extended-toolkit

After installing the latest version of Extended WPF toolkit in my Net 6 solution nothing of the Extended WPF Toolkit shows up.

- There is no 'packages' folder in the folder of the project
- After creating a new tab in the toolbox and selecting 'choose items' nothing of the WPF
  Extended toolkit shows up

I tried reinstalling and relaunching VS 2022 to no success.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, been around many discussions and it seemslike the community toolkit is meant to be integrated with UWP platform (as suggested there : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/getting-started?source=docs). Not sure if it's linked to the issue though but it's my last found hint...

Comment: Ok after investigating further, i wasn't using Extended WPF toolkit from Xceed but instead CommunityToolkit.Common... My bad ! Anyway as I was looking for a specific additionnal control, I successfull ended up with the nugget :  DotNetProjects.WpfToolkit.DataVisualization